# Image store and retrieve in Python using matplotlib and opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, sqlite

This code is intended to store the passed image using `imread` function in OpenCV and then, on entering the fruit name and clicking the identify button, all images stored in the database with that name should get displayed. I get an error, mentioned after the code.

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from tkinter import messagebox
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def add_command():
    fname=Fruitname.get()
    iname=Imagename.get()
    img = cv2.imread(str(iname),0) 
    conn=sqlite3.connect('Fruits.db')
    with conn:
        cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FRUITSINFO(NAME TEXT,IMAGENAME TEXT)')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO FRUITSINFO(NAME,IMAGENAME) VALUES(?,?)',(fname,iname))

    conn.commit()
def identify_command():
    fname=Fruitname.get()
    conn=sqlite3.connect('Fruits.db')
    with conn:
        cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT IMAGENAME FROM FRUITSINFO WHERE NAME = ?", (fname,))
    v=cursor.fetchone()[0]
    s=str(v)
    imgplot=plt.imshow(s)
    plt.show()

root=Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
width = 900
height = 500
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)
Fruitname = StringVar()
Imagename = StringVar()
Top=Frame(root,width=900,height=50,bd=8,relief="raise")
Top.pack(side=TOP)
Left=Frame(root,width=300,height=500,relief="raise")
Left.pack(side=LEFT)
Right=Frame(root,width=600,height=500,bd=8,relief="raise")
Right.pack(side=RIGHT)
Forms = Frame(Left, width=300, height=450)
Forms.pack(side=TOP)
Buttons = Frame(Left, width=300, height=100, bd=8, relief="raise")
Buttons.pack(side=BOTTOM)
txt_title = Label(Top, width=900, font=('arial', 24), text = "Fruit Detection")
txt_title.pack()
txt_fruitname = Label(Forms, text="Fruit name:", font=('arial', 16), bd=15)
txt_fruitname.grid(row=0, stick="e")
txt_imagename = Label(Forms, text="Image name:", font=('arial', 16), bd=15)
txt_imagename.grid(row=1, stick="e")
txt_result = Label(Buttons)
txt_result.pack(side=TOP)
fruitname = Entry(Forms, textvariable=Fruitname, width=30)
fruitname.grid(row=0, column=1)
imagename = Entry(Forms, textvariable=Imagename, width=30)
imagename.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn_add = Button(Buttons, width=10, text="ADD",command=add_command)
btn_add.pack(side=LEFT)
btn_identify = Button(Buttons, width=10, text="IDENTIFY",command=identify_command)
btn_identify.pack(side=LEFT)
btn_exit = Button(Buttons, width=10, text="Exit")
btn_exit.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Following error is generated:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\prath\Desktop\Mini\fruitdetect_gui.py", line 27, in identify_command
    imgplot=plt.imshow(s)
  File "C:\Users\prath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2699, in imshow
    None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\prath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\prath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5494, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Users\prath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 634, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float
```

Comment: What is the value and type of `v`?

Comment: @Berriel I am using it to store the image retrieved from the database using the fetchall function

Comment: But, again: what is the datatype (`type(v)`) and the value (`print(v)`) of `v`. Add this info to the question.

Comment: Check the newly edited question. I used s to store the first image name from the table, converted it into a string and used it in the imshow function but now I get a new error mentioned at the end of the question.

Comment: @Berriel v is of type str and content is name of the image i uploaded i.e. 'apple.png'

Comment: I did not ask about the current `v`, but the previous one, before the edit. Also, I answered your previous question and you did not consider to mark as answer, therefore I assume you do need help.

Comment: Yeah I do need help in displaying all images associated with the name I enter. What info do you need to help ?

Comment: I need to know the type and value of the old `v`, the one from `fetchall()`

Comment: The type was 'list'

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you check?

Comment: Yeah but it is just displaying the first image I added with the name 'Apple'. I want to display all the images

Comment: Can you add the content of the return of `fetchall` to your question? The `vs` of my answer.

Comment: You mean the contents of the original fetchall or the one in your updated answer ?

Comment: The original. They are supposed to be the same, aren't they? Did I change something that I did not notice?

Comment: The contents of vs: [('apple.png',), ('apple1.png',), ('apple2.png',)]

Comment: Then my answer should be displaying all these images (`apple.png`, `apple1.png`, `apple2.png`), one at a time.

Comment: Yeah but it displays the first image, then I close the image window but nothing happens afterwards. The other images get displayed when I close the tkinter window by using the 'Exit' command button only and not before.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You should not mix these things. You should open a window with `tkinter` and display the images there. I would say that this is a different question and you should open a new one to solve this issue. I would recommend you to create an MCVE removing the `sqlite3` requirement; in this way, more people would try to help. If you do so, please post the link to the question here so we can go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.imshow(...)` expects an image. Maybe what you are looking for is:

```py
def identify_command():
    fname = Fruitname.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Fruits.db')
    with conn:
        cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT IMAGENAME FROM FRUITSINFO WHERE NAME = ?", (fname,))
    v = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    image = mpimg.imread(str(v))  # << idk why you deleted this line on the edit
    imgplot = plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

If you use `fetchall(...)`, it would be something like this:

```py
    vs = cursor.fetchall()               # vs = [('apple.png',), ('apple1.png',), ('apple2.png',)]
    for v in vs:                         # e.g., v = ('apple.png',)
        image = mpimg.imread(str(v[0]))  # e.g., v[0] = 'apple.png'
        imgplot = plt.imshow(image)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I just figured that out. But what if I want to display all images in the database associated with the name I provide at fname=Fruitname.get() ?

Comment: @PratheekMenon if this answer was helpful, consider marking as answer (since you cannot up-vote yet). About your second question, you would have to iterate over all the values. To help you with that, I would need you to tell me the datatype and values that I asked on my first comment.

Comment: Well since I am using fetchone()[0], the type is str and content is 'apple.png' which is the name of the image I added to the database.